# CLLocationManager returns kCLErrorDenied when running as a console application (without using UIApplication)

Tags: ios, background, console, gps, cllocationmanager

I'm develops console application for iOS (iPhone, iPad)
My application do not use UIApplication
I use the following code:

```
MDCoreLocation *gps = [[MDCoreLocation alloc] init];
CLLocationManager *manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[manager setDelegate:gps];
[manager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
[manager startUpdatingLocation];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] run];
```

But the method locationManager:didFailWithError: in delegate class MDCoreLocation was called with error **kCLErrorDenied**.

Location Services in User Preferences is ON, but my console application do not present in applications list.

Do You have any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Location apps need to display the location confirmation alert before they are allowed to use the users location. Since you have no UI I guess this won't work.

Comment: Can I programmatically bypass this limitation, if my application is run as root process?

Comment: I don't know. Is this a jailbroken device?

Comment: Yes, jailbroken iPhone 3GS with iPhone OS 4.2.1.